# How to display a connection between 2 elements of 2 different ListViews in the same screen?

Tags: android, listview, overlay

Imagine that I have 2 ListViews on the same screen, like this:

[image: 2 ListViews on the same screen]

So, now I want to connect one element from the left to one element in the right. That connection should be represented using a line.

Any item from the left can be connected to a item from the right. And one item from the left can be connected to multiple rights and one right can only have one left (although this kind of restrictions It should be simple if the first problem is solved).

I can't see a way to do this considering that an user can scroll both lists and that connection should be redrawn after a scroll. Also a connection with a item that is not on the screen (that was scrolled) should have some kind of representation.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

**EDIT**

The size of each item will be larger so connections will not be that confusing. In max we will have 5-6 connections at a time.

Comment: Is there only one connection between each item in the left and right columns? (ie item1Left -> item7Right only and item1Left <- item7Right only)

Comment: Is there a way to have your connecting points a fixed point so that it never changes with the scroll?

Comment: @Sam It can have more than one connection. Every item on the left can connect with every item on the right. Also 1 item from the left can connect to several from the right.

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW I couldn't understand your question. But it is important for users to be able to scroll because the number of items is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the center point of each item you want to connect, and then use drawLines() in android.graphics.canvas

[drawLines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

[view.getLocationOnScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29)

Comment: What does `view.getLocationOnScreen` returns when the view is out of the screen?
Also, how can I know what is the x I need to add to the first listview so I can draw a line from the right edge into the second list view?

At last... I need a way to refresh all lines when someone uses the scroll...

Comment: Don't know what is returned if the view is off screen. You would have to determine that using trial and error. As far as the edge, you'll have to use getMeasuredWidth of the view and do the proper math. And override the onTouchEvent of the listview to draw the lines would probably be your best bet

Comment: The only problem I get now is when a user scrolls and the view connected gets out of the screen. `getLocationOnScreen` gives some strange values depending on how far the view is...

Comment: You could use the ListView's getFirstVisiblePosition() and getLastVisiblePosition() methods to determine if the view your checking has an index between those two, and if not, could easily determine if it is off the screen or on.

Comment: But I want to keep on following even though they are out of the screen. The problem is that a list view replaces the view when I do some scrolling...

Comment: Once it's off screen, all you could really do is track which side of the screen it is off of, I'm afraid... unless something can be inferred from the strange values of getLocationOnScreen... what does it return when the view is off screen?

Comment: The values of LocationOnScreen are consistent with a replacement on the listview. When I scroll down the view gets something till -70 in y then it starts to get values like 700~. It seems like the view wrapped from the top to the bottom of the listview.

Comment: then I think you'll have to check the index of the view and compare to the first visible and the last visible to determine off screen location, and then if it's on screen use the screen location.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping every connection, with or without scrolling, sounds like there will be lines going every where and difficult to read. If you set a clickListener on each item that will highlight each connection to the opposing column, that would be easier to read, but you would have to click on every item to see all the connections one at a time.

Comment: This items are small for the purpose of testing/spiking. In the final result I intend to have 4-5 items at the time. I really need to see the connection between items without touching every item.